# Facebook on Android without using fragments

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I would like to implement a complete management of the basic things about facebook on an app, so requesting personal information, friend list and posting on the wall. All of this should be done without the use of fragments, using API 3.0.

Right now I'm stuck on the only example I have got that makes this, that is SessionLoginSampleActivity. My program right now is nothing more than that example, adapted on my layout, you can find it on the end of the post.
Unfortunately that example does not go beyond authentication, and I cannot realize how to make asynchronous talk with facebook and retrieve user data and all that stuff.

Is there a *complete* example somewhere that does it?

After the authentication, how can I asynchronously retrieve my user picture, my name and my friend list, without fragments? Where should I write it? Should I create a new listener?

The question may appear weird and basic, but I'm really getting crazy with the facebook API that looks so powerful and yet very very obscure to my eyes.

Please don't answer me: "use fragments!" :)

Thank you very much!

```
public class FbActivity extends Activity {
private Button buttonLoginLogout, b_friends, b_challenge;
private TextView t_instructions, t_username;
private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
private Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();

public FbActivity() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook_activity);
    findAll();

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session == null) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
        }
        if (session == null) {
            session = new Session(this);
        }
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    }

    updateView();
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

private void findAll() {
    buttonLoginLogout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoginLogout);
    t_instructions = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.instructionsOrLink);
    b_friends = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonFindFriend);
    b_challenge = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonFindNewChallenge);
    profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView)findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
    t_username = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);
}



private void setVisibility(boolean opened) {
    if (opened) {
        buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.logout);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogout(); }
        });
        t_instructions.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
        b_friends.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        b_challenge.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        t_username.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        profilePictureView.setVisibility(ProfilePictureView.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        buttonLoginLogout.setText(R.string.login);
        buttonLoginLogout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) { onClickLogin(); }
        });
        t_instructions.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        b_friends.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        b_challenge.setVisibility(Button.INVISIBLE);
        t_username.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
        profilePictureView.setVisibility(ProfilePictureView.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
private void updateView() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    setVisibility(session.isOpened());
}

private void onClickLogin() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(this, true, statusCallback);
    }
}
private void onClickLogout() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (!session.isClosed()) {
        session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
    }
}   
private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        updateView();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: check my answer below hope it will help you to get initial idea about how to integrate Facebook and user details.

Comment: There's really nothing in the core API itself that relies on Fragments. The only parts that use Fragments are the UI elements (friend picker, place picker, etc). If you just want to make Graph API requests, try looking in the Request class. It has a lot of methods that help you make async requests to FB.

Answer (score 2):

We have a need to maintain further bw compatibility than that. What we did was to pull the v1.2.2 version of the facebook API from github, and use that instead. The docs are harder to find, but the sample applications are directly usable...and no fragments are anywhere in sight.

```
git clone git://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk.git
cd facebook-and*
git checkout v1.2.2
```

It looks like we'll also have to add a few things, like newer version of images into their library project, but that isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you first have a page called logged_off.xml where you just have your loginButton and your purpose is to login and then, after you have correctly logged, change your view to another page called logged_in.xml.

so you have:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.logged_off);
Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);

loginButton = (Button) findviedbyid(R.id.loginButton);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) { 
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback).setPermissions(PERMISSIONS));  
}
    });

//here we check if our session exists. if it does exists we directly go to our page logged_in.xml otherwise we stay in logged_off.xml waiting for the user to click on our loginButton

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback, savedInstanceState);
    }
    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session(this);
    }
    Session.setActiveSession(session);
}else{
if(session.session.isOpened()){
setContentView(R.layout.logged_in);
}
}
}
```

This function is called after we make an attempt to log in so here we check if we actually logged in correctly and if we did we just change our page to logged_in.xml. So change this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(session.session.isOpened()){
    setContentView(R.layout.logged_in);
}
}
```

of course you can change setContentView(R.layout.logged_in); with whatever you want.

hope it helped!

PS: keep all these functions:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
super.onStop();
Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Session.saveSession(session, outState);
}

private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
@Override
public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    //updateView();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take the Facebook developers tutorials as reference and just take off all things related with fragments, like `fragments manager`, keep the `UiLifecycleHelper` and `onSessionStateChange` method by the other hand are necessaries and allow you to know the state of the session and its changes.

Here´s an example of onSessionStateChange and how you can modified it to start a new activity, I´m developing an App without fragments

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                if (state.isOpened()) { 
                    // If the session state is open:
                    // Show the SendRequest Activity
                    Intent sendRequest = new Intent(this, SendRequest.class);  // If session isOpened we launch the INTENT to Pick Friends
                    startActivity(sendRequest);
                }else if (state.isClosed()){
                    uiHelper.onResume();
                }
        }
```